# ASCII art of letters, with the letters using their own characters

Tags: shell, banner, ascii-art

If I execute

```
banner ABC
```

I get:

```
   #    ######   #####
  # #   #     # #     #
 #   #  #     # #
#     # ######  #
####### #     # #
#     # #     # #     #
#     # ######   #####
```

and another program, `figlet`, has more elaborate fonts and mechanisms for joining adjacent characters, e.g.:

```
    _    ____   ____ 
   / \  | __ ) / ___|
  / _ \ |  _ \| |    
 / ___ \| |_) | |___ 
/_/   \_\____/ \____|
```

but what if I want to have each letter printed using just that letter, i.e.:

```
   A    BBBBBB   CCCCC
  A A   B     B C     C
 A   A  B     B C
A     A BBBBBB  C
AAAAAAA B     B C
A     A B     B C     C
A     A BBBBBB   CCCCC
```

or better yet, something more compact, like:

```
  A    BBBB   CCCC 
 A A   B   B C     
A   A  BBBB  C     
AAAAA  B   B C     
A   A  BBBB   CCCC
```

? What's the simplest way to make that happen?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are four optional fonts for `figlet` which use the single-ASCII-character letters themselves to draw larger versions of these letter: Either [here](http://www.figlet.org/fontdb.cgi) (`alphabet`, `letters` and `tanja`) [here](http://www-personal.umich.edu/~knassen/figfonts/other/) (same) or [here](https://packages.debian.org/stretch/all/toilet-fonts/filelist) (`letter`):

[alphabet](http://www.figlet.org/fontdb_example.cgi?font=alphabet.flf)

```
    b          AA  BBBB   CCC 
    b         A  A B   B C    
 aa bbb   ccc AAAA BBBB  C    
a a b  b c    A  A B   B C    
aaa bbb   ccc A  A BBBB   CCC
```

[letter](https://packages.debian.org/stretch/all/toilet-fonts/filelist)

```
  A   BBBB   CCC    A   BBBB   CCC  
 A A  B   B C   C  A A  B   B C   C 
AAAAA BBBB  C     AAAAA BBBB  C     
A   A B   B C   C A   A B   B C   C 
A   A BBBB   CCC  A   A BBBB   CCC
```

[letters](http://www.figlet.org/fontdb_example.cgi?font=letters.flf)

```
        bb               AAA   BBBBB    CCCCC  
  aa aa bb        cccc  AAAAA  BB   B  CC    C 
 aa aaa bbbbbb  cc     AA   AA BBBBBB  CC      
aa  aaa bb   bb cc     AAAAAAA BB   BB CC    C 
 aaa aa bbbbbb   ccccc AA   AA BBBBBB   CCCCC
```

[tanja](http://www.figlet.org/fontdb_example.cgi?font=tanja.flf)

```
        b)                A)aa   B)bbbb     C)ccc  
        b)               A)  aa  B)   bb   C)   cc 
a)AAAA  b)BBBB   c)CCCC A)    aa B)bbbb   C)       
 a)AAA  b)   BB c)      A)aaaaaa B)   bb  C)       
a)   A  b)   BB c)      A)    aa B)    bb  C)   cc 
 a)AAAA b)BBBB   c)CCCC A)    aa B)bbbbb    C)ccc
```

And maybe `doh`

```
$ figlet -f doh abcABC
                 bbbbbbbb                                
                 b::::::b                                
                 b::::::b                                
                 b::::::b                                
                  b:::::b                                
  aaaaaaaaaaaaa   b:::::bbbbbbbbb        cccccccccccccccc
  a::::::::::::a  b::::::::::::::bb    cc:::::::::::::::c
  aaaaaaaaa:::::a b::::::::::::::::b  c:::::::::::::::::c
           a::::a b:::::bbbbb:::::::bc:::::::cccccc:::::c
    aaaaaaa:::::a b:::::b    b::::::bc::::::c     ccccccc
  aa::::::::::::a b:::::b     b:::::bc:::::c             
 a::::aaaa::::::a b:::::b     b:::::bc:::::c             
a::::a    a:::::a b:::::b     b:::::bc::::::c     ccccccc
a::::a    a:::::a b:::::bbbbbb::::::bc:::::::cccccc:::::c
a:::::aaaa::::::a b::::::::::::::::b  c:::::::::::::::::c
 a::::::::::aa:::ab:::::::::::::::b    cc:::::::::::::::c
  aaaaaaaaaa  aaaabbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb       cccccccccccccccc

               AAA               BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB           CCCCCCCCCCCCC
              A:::A              B::::::::::::::::B       CCC::::::::::::C
             A:::::A             B::::::BBBBBB:::::B    CC:::::::::::::::C
            A:::::::A            BB:::::B     B:::::B  C:::::CCCCCCCC::::C
           A:::::::::A             B::::B     B:::::B C:::::C       CCCCCC
          A:::::A:::::A            B::::B     B:::::BC:::::C              
         A:::::A A:::::A           B::::BBBBBB:::::B C:::::C              
        A:::::A   A:::::A          B:::::::::::::BB  C:::::C              
       A:::::A     A:::::A         B::::BBBBBB:::::B C:::::C              
      A:::::AAAAAAAAA:::::A        B::::B     B:::::BC:::::C              
     A:::::::::::::::::::::A       B::::B     B:::::BC:::::C              
    A:::::AAAAAAAAAAAAA:::::A      B::::B     B:::::B C:::::C       CCCCCC
   A:::::A             A:::::A   BB:::::BBBBBB::::::B  C:::::CCCCCCCC::::C
  A:::::A               A:::::A  B:::::::::::::::::B    CC:::::::::::::::C
 A:::::A                 A:::::A B::::::::::::::::B       CCC::::::::::::C
AAAAAAA                   AAAAAAABBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB           CCCCCCCCCCCCC
```

Answer (score 9):

Another option is to use the [alphabet](http://www.figlet.org/fontdb_example.cgi?font=alphabet.flf) font with FIGlet:

```
$ wget http://www.figlet.org/fonts/alphabet.flf
$ figlet -f alphabet.flf ABC
 AA  BBBB   CCC 
A  A B   B C    
AAAA BBBB  C    
A  A B   B C    
A  A BBBB   CCC
```

Answer (score 5):

With `toilet`:

```
$ toilet -f letter ABC
  A   BBBB   CCC  
 A A  B   B C   C 
AAAAA BBBB  C     
A   A B   B C   C 
A   A BBBB   CCC
```

That `letter` font is a `figlet` font that comes with the `toilet-fonts` package on Debian at least. After that package is installed, you can also use that font with `figlet` (`figlet -f letter`).

Comment: Nice, I didn’t know about [TOIlet](http://caca.zoy.org/wiki/toilet) (written by Sam Hocevar, there’s a surprise). That works with FIGlet too!

Comment: @StephenKitt, see edit. `toilet` uses the same fonts as `figlet`

Comment: Yes, TOIlet and FIGlet are now compatible with each other — TOIlet was always able to use FIGlet fonts, and FIGlet 2.2.4 added support for TOIlet fonts. (Strictly speaking “letter” is a TOIlet font.)

Answer (score 3):

<sub>(This was the initial answer to the question.)</sub>

One option would be to modify the source of sysvbanner. Apparently that's not too difficult, [here](https://github.com/uffejakobsen/sysvbanner/blob/master/banner.c) it is. Essentially just replacing `#`'s with the appropriate characters, once.

I would like other answers that doesn't involve compiling a binary, though.